# CloudFlare получить статистику сайта через API

Tags: cloudflare

api.cloudflare дает такую ссылку
[https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{account_identifier}/rum/site_info/{site_identifier}](https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/%7Baccount_identifier%7D/rum/site_info/%7Bsite_identifier%7D)

account_identifier я так понимаю Acoount ID
Что такое site_identifier ?